# Detecting the end of video scrubbing in Microsoft browsers

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, html5-video, microsoft-edge

I have a video, and I want to run a process as long as the video is playing. When the video is paused, I pause my process. When the video is being scrubbed by the user, I pause my process, and then restart the process when scrubbing is finished. This means I need to detect the start and end of scrubbing, when the user releases the mouse button.

```
var video = document.querySelector("video");
video.addEventListener("play", function () { console.log("Starting"); });
video.addEventListener("pause", function () { console.log("Pausing") });
video.addEventListener("seeking", function () { console.log("Pausing") });
```

This works fine in Chrome, Firefox, etc. When the scrubbing starts, the browser fires a series of `seeking` events. When scrubbing finishes (mouse button is released), we get `seeked`, followed immediately by `play` (if the video was playing originally).

In IE or Edge, I get a completely different series of events. When scrubbing starts, the browser fires a series of `seeking` events, each followed immediately by a `seeked`. When scrubbing finishes I never see a `play` event.

How can I detect the end of scrubbing in Microsoft browsers?

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/neilduncan/pen/GVWVGV?editors=1111)

Comment: You could ask to add a `play` event after `seeking` in Microsoft browsers in Feedback Hub. You can refer to [this article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4021566/windows-10-send-feedback-to-microsoft-with-feedback-hub) to see how to send feedback. Once you have submitted this feature in Feedback Hub, hope you can share the link in here, in this way community members who have the same requirement can vote on it which can probably raise the priority of this feature.

Answer (score 1):

I reproduced the issue on my side. I tried many ways and found no way to detect if the scrubbing is finished in IE and Edge. I think it is designed like this in IE and Edge.

As a workaround, you could pause the video after seeking event in IE and Edge, then start it manually like the code below:

```
var video = document.querySelector("video");
    video.addEventListener("play", function () {
        console.log("Starting");
    });
    video.addEventListener("pause", function () {
        console.log("Pausing");
    });
    video.addEventListener("seeking", function () {
        console.log("Seeking");
        //check if the browser is IE or Edge
        if (document.documentMode || /Edge/.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
            video.pause();
        }        
    });
```